# SQL Server 2012 pivot error

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm doing a dynamic pivot to create a cross tab with dates. The @Query generated is :-

```
SELECT [R_Ref]
    ,CONCAT(datepart(yyyy,[Transaction_Date]), '-', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), datepart(M,[Transaction_Date])), 2)) as 'Month'
    ,[Transaction_Value] 
     FROM [T-Files].[dbo].[T_Transactions] 
     as MyTX
PIVOT (
     SUM(MyTX.[Transaction_Value])
     FOR MyTX.[Month] IN (  [2016-05], [2016-06], [2016-07])
 ) p
```

but this generates these errors

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'Month'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Transaction_Value'.
```

I can run the top select without the pivot fine, what's wrong in the PIVOT statement?
TIA :o)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put pivot source in `sub-select` since you are making some manipulation to generate `Month`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT [R_Ref],
               Concat(Datepart(yyyy, [Transaction_Date]), '-', RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), Datepart(M, [Transaction_Date])), 2)) AS 'Month',
               MyTX.[Transaction_Value]
        FROM   [T-Files].[dbo].[T_Transactions] AS MyTX) A
       PIVOT ( Sum([Transaction_Value])
             FOR [Month] IN ( [2016-05],
                                   [2016-06],
                                   [2016-07]) ) p
```

Comment: I think you want to replace the `MyTX` aliases in your pivot with `A`, since that's the only alias in play by that point (or just remove them entirely, since again, there's only one rowset involved)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - My bad,.. Updated

Comment: Next question ... I trimmed the months column headers quite a lot as the data goes back to 2009. Most 'cells' have NULL returned as the data is quite sparse and many rows won't have any data at all. Is there a way to populate the results with a 0 instead of NULL when there is no data for a row in the columns? I would still want to see rows with no data

Comment: @JohnnyC - Thats a new question.